# Help! Unable to verify Token Contract, Where can get ByteCode and ABI?

Tags: etherscan, abi

Receiving the following errors:
Note: Contract was created during Txn#
Result: Does not match the input creation bytecode found at this address

Error! Unable to generate Contract ByteCode and ABI

For some reason, the end of my Input Data does not give me a working Bytecode to use where others do.
Here's the transaction which made the contract: https://etherscan.io/tx/0x41c4bf0eb9a58d1e70b595fea1a1147671c0fbcdfe13445b9569642827e47695

Any help is appreciated, I've been stuck at this point for some days, and completely clueless.

Cheers!

Comment: I think is different. I asked how to get Constructor Arguments ABI-encoded.